# Pontiac 2009 Vibe Cool to Heat dial won't budge

Tags: pontiac, vibe, heater-control

It looks like it is stuck or frozen or broken.  I noticed it was hard to turn earlier but now it won't move at all.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly are you trying to solve as I don't really see a question here. Help us out a little bit with some more detail, if you would please.

Comment: Try spraying some kind of cleaner in there? Maybe it's just sticky from fluids or something.